# Memory consumption increases indefinitely when an extra multiply operation is added to one line of code

Tags: arm, embedded, embedded-linux, cortex-a8

I have a C/C++ project running on an embedded Linux device (ARM Cortex A9).

I can SSH into the device while it is running, and check the process stats with "top"

I have narrowed down my issue to one line of code.

```
temp = 1.2*buf[j]-w*buf[j+1];
```

Where temp is a double, buf is a double array, w is a double, and j is int32.

When the code runs, the memory usage of the application continues to increase until it crashes (~10 minutes)...  If I change the line to say

```
temp = buf[j]-w*buf[j+1];
```

The memory consumption does NOT increase!

What is going on?  I have never encountered anything like this.

Comment: It's possible that the error is completely unrelated to that line of code. However, by changing that line, and recompiling, you've rearranged the memory layout that the app uses. Hence, a rogue pointer that causes the memory problem ends up pointing to something harmless (or something not quite as noticeable) after the recompile. In short, you have the dreaded [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105123).

Comment: Thanks @user3386109 for the reply!